# It there a way to cache OpenMDAO component outputs to avoid duplicate executions?

Tags: optimization, solver, openmdao

I am writing a model consists of five subsystems. The first subsystem is generates data for other subsystems using the inputs it does not solve anything iteratively, therefore its outputs not changed during computation. I want it calls once the compute method just like the initialization. How can I write a model that calls once in run_model and calls every time just once in run_driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to be sure without more details, but you mention "iterative" so Im guessing you have a solver at the top level of your model and there is a component not involved in that solver loop, but that is getting called each time the solver iterates.

The solution to this is to make a sub-group in your model that has just the components that need to iterate. Put your only-run-once component at the top of the model, along with that group. Put the iterative solver on the sub-group.

An alternative solution is to add a bit of caching to your component, so it checks its inputs to see if they have changed. If they have, re-run. If they have not, just keep the old answer.

Here is an example that includes both features (note: the solver in this example does not converge because its a toy problem that doesn't have a valid physical solution. I just threw it together to illustrate the model structure and caching)

[image: OpenMDAO Model with sub-solver and caching component]

```
import openmdao.api as om
# from openmdao.utils.assert_utils import assert_check_totals


class StingyComp(om.ExplicitComponent): 

    def setup(self): 

        self.add_input('x1', val=2.)
        self.add_input('x2', val=3.)

        self.add_output('x')

        self._input_hash = None


    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

        x1 = inputs['x1'][0] # pull the scalar out so you can hash it
        x2 = inputs['x2'][0]

        print("running StingyComp")
        current_input_hash = hash((x1, x2))
        if self._input_hash != current_input_hash : 
            print('    ran compute')
            outputs['x'] = 2*x1 + x2**2
            self._input_hash = current_input_hash
        else: 
            print('    skipped compute')


class NormalComp(om.ExplicitComponent): 

    def setup(self): 

        self.add_input('x1', val=2.)
        self.add_input('x2', val=3.)

        self.add_output('y')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

        x1 = inputs['x1']
        x2 = inputs['x2']

        print("running normal Comp")
        outputs['y'] = x1 + x2


p = om.Problem()



p.model.add_subsystem('run_once1', NormalComp(), promotes=['*'])
p.model.add_subsystem('run_once2', StingyComp(), promotes=['*'])

sub_group = p.model.add_subsystem('sub_group', om.Group(), promotes=['*']) # transparent group that could hold sub-solver
sub_group.add_subsystem('C1', om.ExecComp('f1 = f2**2 + 1.5 * x - y**2.5'), promotes=['*'])
sub_group.add_subsystem('C2', om.ExecComp('f2 = f1**2 + x**1.5 - 2.5*y'), promotes=['*'])
sub_group.nonlinear_solver = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems=False)
sub_group.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()


p.setup()


print('first run')
p.run_model()

print('second run, same inputs')
p.run_model()

p['x1'] = 10
p['x2'] = 27.5

print('third run, new inputs')
p.run_model()
```

Comment: I simply discretize using geometry input. Unless the geometry changes (initially given), no need to call during the solution. In the parent group, I was using set_order, force it to call initially, saw in N2 diagram and used LinearRunOnce as a solver.I just made a simple print prompt in the compute method and calls every iteration and I want to make sure it does not cause a computational load.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the system only needs to call compute once, you set a flag when compute is called, and from that point forward don't recompute the outputs.  The outputs will remain unchanged since they're not being overridden by compute.  Just be careful with this technique, since if an input does unknowingly change you'll get incorrect outputs or partials.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. If you could provide a sample run script that would let us give a much more clear answer.

Comment: @JustinGray thank you for the example. My code is working (converges) this way.

For clarity, my question was "is there a way not prompting 'running StingyComp' in second run", this way also accelerates my optimization significantly.